# How to make an NTFS partition on HDD (12.10)

Tags: installation, 12.10, ntfs, windows-xp, format

I currently own a netbook running Ubuntu 12.10 and i want to install windows XP on it. I have the installation file on my pendrive as my netbook doesnt have disk drive. but when I opened the setup.exe, it didnt open. So i installed WINE on my netbook,

I opened the file and setup opens, but when I try to install it it says-
" NO valid system partitions were found, setup is unable to continue"

Then I decided to make that pendrive a bootable one,, so i could install XP, so i downloaded rufus, it didnt run on my system idk why. So i did some research and found a video which showed to make my pendrive NTFS, and then use unetbootin to make it bootable.

Si i downloaded the 7zip application and then selected the XP iso for unetbootin... I waited  for like 10 mins for the process to finish. then i rebooted and booted from the pendrive,

but it had a small blue screen saying unetbootin ( something like that) and a timer below counting down from 10 for something(for automatic boot AFAI remember), and it said press tab to edit options.and after counting to 10 the whole process starts again :(

Please help me install XP on my netbook. Can anyone tell me the solution or an easy way to install XP??  I think that making an NTFS partition on my existing 120 GB HDD will work but im afraid that it will delete ubuntu. I only have this PC at the moment HELP!

P.S. please keep in mind that im a total noob

Answer (score 0):

Install GPart on your Ubuntu.

Open Gpart and select your HDD and make some free space by resize/delete option.

make usb drive as bootable and boot XP from your usb drive.